# Finding the radius of convergence for $a_n = (-1)^n\frac{(x-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm trying to find the radius of convergence for the series with $a_n = (-1)^n\frac{(x-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}$. I have no solution to look up, so I'm looking for confirmation on whether my solving process is correct.

In order for the series to be convergent,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}|(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(x-1)^{n+1}}{2^{n+2}} \times \frac{2^{n+1}}{(-1)^n(x-1)^n}|<1$$

Which reduces to

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{(x-1)(-1)}{2}| <1$$

Since this is a modulus, $(-1) = 1$ under the modulus.

Leaving me with:

$$R = \frac{x-1}{2} < 1$$

And for this to be true, $x$ must be less than $3/2$. Thus,

$$ R = 3/2$$.

I'm a bit skeptical on how I just dropped the limit operator, but I think this may make sense. Please let me know if any component of my logic or algebra was incorrect in this procedure.

Comment: You should not include the $(x-1)^n$ term. When calculating the radius of convergence we only use the coefficients. Then the interval of convergence is $(-1-R,-1+R)$.

Comment: This supposes the O.P. uses  *Hadamard's formula*.

Answer (score 0):

What you shouldn't have dropped is tha absolute value. The condition is 
$$|x-1|<2,$$
which means the radius of convergence is $2$, and the *interval of convergence* (in the real domain) is
$$1-2<x<1+2,\enspace \text{i.e. }\enspace -1<x<3.$$

Comment: Ah I see. But why does $|x-1| < 2$ imply the radius of convergence $= 2$? There are almost $4$ integers $x$ can take to still satisfy convergence, so why is it $2$? This might be an ugly hypothesis, but is the radius of convergence $2$, while the "diameter" (that may be grossly not analogous) would be tending towards $4$?

Comment: Saying the radius of convergence is $2$ doesn't mean it does not converge for $|x-1|=2$. It only means it converges if $<2$ and diverges if $>2$. Indeed it converges if $x=-1$ and diverges  if $x=3$. Also the radius or the diameter  is the same for $(a,b)$ and for $[a,b]$.